# Как массиву спрайтов можно присвоить значение?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть массив спрайтов,у каждого элемента свой цвет и картинка.
Как можно через enum(или другим способом) присвоить значение каждому элементу.как вот на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "присвоить"? Причем здесь enum? На картинке кастомный редактор массива, смею предположить, что это Odin Inspector. В чем в итоге заключается вопрос? В повторении такого же инспектора?

Comment: на карте есть цвет и картинка,например пять пик,они выпадают рандомно и мне нужно знать,что это именно та карта выпала,поэтому каждому спрайту нужно обозначить его цвет и картинку,но не знаю,как это можно сделать

Comment: `каждому спрайту нужно обозначить цвет и картинку` - не понимаю этого. Спрайт - это и есть "картинка", о каком "цвете спрайта" идет речь?

Comment: ну да,как понять что именно 5 пик выпала,а не 9 червей,в этом вопрос,для этого каждый спрайт и нужно обозначить

Comment: Заведите класс и обозначайте так, как вам удобно в вашей программе. То, что представлено на скриншоте - собственный сериализуемый класс.

Comment: а можно пример,пожалуйста